# Why is React component's console.log() is rendering twice?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

### Assumption

We are developing with Laravel 9 + React 18.2.0.
I have finished installing Laravel, React and breeze using [this starter kit](https://readouble.com/laravel/9.x/en/starter-kits.html).
Next, let's look at the contents of resources/js/ Pages/Welcomde.jsx
I added console.log("test") as follows

```
import { Link, Head } from '@inertiajs/react';

export default function Welcome(props) {
    console.log("test"); //<=Add
    return (
        <>
　　　　...
        </>
    );
}
```

I then built the server with `npm run build`, and started the server locally with `php artisan serve`, and checked the initial screen with chrome's developer tools.
As a result, I found that the console outputs the contents of console.log() twice in the console.
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEhf6.png)

### What I want to know

In [this React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), I read that in development mode, **strict mode** is used and rendering is done twice.
However, I am having trouble understanding why this is the case, as even in the **production environment** where I have built the system, the output is being rendered twice.
If you know the reason, please let me know.

### Used profiler

I used profiler based on your comment. Thank you very much. Result of using [profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zza8T.png), "Inertia state update scheduled" was running after the first rendering. "Inertia state update scheduled" was rendered by function L.

```
function L({ children: l, initialPage: c, initialComponent: a, resolveComponent: p, titleCallback: s, onHeadUpdate: S2 }) {
    let [d, P] = (0, import_react2.useState)({ component: a || null, page: c, key: null }), u2 = (0, import_react2.useMemo)(() => Q(typeof window > "u", s || ((f2) => f2), S2 || (() => {
    })), []);
    if ((0, import_react2.useEffect)(() => {
      Oe.init({ initialPage: c, resolveComponent: p, swapComponent: async ({ component: f2, page: e, preserveState: i }) => {
        P((r) => ({ component: f2, page: e, key: i ? r.key : Date.now() }));
      } }), Oe.on("navigate", () => u2.forceUpdate());
    }, []), !d.component)
      return (0, import_react2.createElement)(A2.Provider, { value: u2 }, (0, import_react2.createElement)(E.Provider, { value: d.page }, null));
    let g = l || (({ Component: f2, props: e, key: i }) => {
      let r = (0, import_react2.createElement)(f2, { key: i, ...e });
      return typeof f2.layout == "function" ? f2.layout(r) : Array.isArray(f2.layout) ? f2.layout.concat(r).reverse().reduce((y, T) => (0, import_react2.createElement)(T, { children: y, ...e })) : r;
    });
    return (0, import_react2.createElement)(A2.Provider, { value: u2 }, (0, import_react2.createElement)(E.Provider, { value: d.page }, g({ Component: d.component, key: d.key, props: d.page.props })));
  }
```

What is this function?

Comment: It would render again if the props object changes (even if the props object looks the same but is a different instance).    We can't see what is calling your `Welcome` component so we can't say for sure.

Comment: Going deeper into the last comment, you should install react developer tools and use the profiler on this page to see why the component is re-rendering. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00RoZflFE34